# Why TargetType ="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}" work

Tags: wpf

I am trying to define a style to overwrite the default to make the font darker for a few wpf pages. There are so many fields so I don't want to apply all of them one by one and just want to define that style in the Page.Resources and apply them automatically. However it doesn't work and I have to define the style each time in the lower level. Does anyone know why?

```
    <Style x:Key="SAForeground" 
        TargetType ="{x:Type              igEditors:XamNumericEditor}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
    </Style>

 <igDP:Field Name="LotSize" Label="Lot Size">
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Double}">
            <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}">
                    <Setter Property="Format" Value="###,##0.######" />
                    <Setter Property="ValueType" Value="{x:Type sys:Double}" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />-->
                </Style>
            </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
        </igDP:FieldSettings>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
  </igDP:Field>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the attribute `x:Key="SAForeground"`  from the style? With a Key attribute, it has to be applied explicitly with a Style attribute on the element you're applying it to. Without that, with only a TargetType, it is what we call an "implicit style", which is applied to every element of that type automagically.

Comment: Sorry, I did without key and it didn't work.

Comment: Darn. You could try an implicit style for Field which applies those FieldSettings with that EditorStyle.

Comment: Looks like Field is not even a control name. How would I do that?

Comment: What kind of Target type would I use for Field?

Comment: If you can't define an implicit style with `TargetType="{x:Type igDP:Field}`, I think you're going to have to be going to the Infragistics documentation. I haven't worked with any of their stuff in quite a while, but I seem dimly to recall that they did some things in their own special way with magic resource keys or something.